# Binary Tree Delete Node function not working

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

```
public void removeNode(int data) {
    deleteNode(root, data);
}

public Node deleteNode(Node focus, int data) {
    if(focus == null) {
        System.out.println("Tree empty");
        return null;
    }
    else if(data < focus.data) {
        deleteNode(focus.leftchild, data);
    }
    else if(data > focus.data) {
        deleteNode(focus.rightchild, data);
    }
    else {
        // No child
        if(focus.leftchild == null && focus.rightchild == null) {
            focus = null;
        }
        // one child
        else if(focus.leftchild == null) {
            focus = focus.rightchild;
            System.out.println("here");
        }
        else if(focus.rightchild == null) {
            focus = focus.leftchild;
        }
        // 2 children
        else {
            Node temp = findMin(focus.rightchild);
            focus.data = temp.data;
            deleteNode(focus.rightchild, temp.data);
        }
    }
    return focus;
}

public Node findMin(Node focus) {
    while(focus.leftchild != null) {
        focus = focus.leftchild;
    }
    return focus;
}
```

I have written the above code to delete a node in Binary Search Tree. However for some reason when I run preordertraversal function to print all the nodes, I see that the node is not getting deleted. Can someone please tell me why a node is not getting deleted. The function seems to be right.

Comment: Setting `focus = null` or `focus = focus.rightchild` doesn't deletes the Node `focus`. You just let the variable `focus`, which only exists in this function point to a different node (or `null`). Instead you have to set the variable in the Node's **parent** to a different value!

Comment: Alright! Will try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it! The problem was that I wasn't traversing the tree the right way. Also I did a mistake in the condition of having two children. I didn't set the right focus.rightchild. Here is the updated code

```
public Node deleteNode(Node focus, int data) {
    if(focus == null) {
        System.out.println("Tree empty");
        return null;
    }
    else if(data < focus.data) {
        focus.leftchild = deleteNode(focus.leftchild, data);
    }
    else if(data > focus.data) {
        focus.rightchild = deleteNode(focus.rightchild, data);
    }
    else {
        // No child
        if(focus.leftchild == null && focus.rightchild == null) {
            focus = null;
        }
        // one child
        else if(focus.leftchild == null) {
            focus = focus.rightchild;
            System.out.println("here");
        }
        else if(focus.rightchild == null) {
            focus = focus.leftchild;
        }
        // 2 children
        else {
            Node temp = findMin(focus.rightchild);
            focus.data = temp.data;
            focus.rightchild = deleteNode(focus.rightchild, temp.data);
        }
    }
    return focus;
}
```